# Would my question be allowed on this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked a question on the Movies & TV site that was closed because it was a "list question". I understand that interpretation, but it's technically a Yes/No question.

[**Is Firefly the only Sci-Fi that shows the camera lens for video chat?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101683/is-firefly-the-only-sci-fi-that-shows-the-camera-lens-for-video-chat)

If the answer is "no", with just a single example, it would answer the question and I'd accept it.

**Is there any chance this site would accept the question?**

If not, that's fine... but can anyone recommend another site (SE or otherwise) where I could ask the question?

Comment: [Hal 9000](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDha7nj4s10)

Comment: There's also this sequence; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWwo6JpMceg. The camera is "smart" and has face-tracking, but it's basically a skype call.

Comment: that second video sold me. I see the camera lens above the screen, just like in Firefly. That's definitely a correct answer - if you want to post it as one, I'd accept it.

Comment: Alas, the question is a) Closed and b) I don't have an account there and no intention of creating one.

Comment: @Valorum Someone on the Movies&TV site reminded me of our primary purpose: creating a good source of information. So I'm going to delete my other question and repost it on this site, in a way that is undoubtedly on-topic. Your HAL9000 answer is totally correct, so if you want to post it as such, I'll accept it. (otherwise I'll just self-answer - which is weird but technically allowed)

Answer (score 1):

With a minor edit, the question would certainly be on-topic here:

> Is Firefly the *first* Sci-Fi that shows the camera lens for video chat?

Your original version of the question could probably be argued either way, but this slightly changed version would be fine, a typical question under the [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) tag. I think it would also give you what you're looking for: if *Firefly* were the only one, then it'd definitely be the first one, and if it were the first one but there were others after it, then you might argue those were inspired by it.

---

<sub>(Personally, I *downvoted* this question. There's a lot of sci-fi out there, and it's virtually impossible that a simple idea like "realistic video chat" first appeared in a popular 2000s TV show. Even if I can't think of an earlier example offhand, to me this question falls into the same category as [Was Harry Potter the first magic series to use wands?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9069/17) However, that doesn't change the fact that it would be **on-topic**.)</sub>

Comment: FWIW the original question appears to be like a slightly altered “any” question which meta states are on topic but they ___always___ attract close votes and generally have a few rounds of close and reopen before settling one way or the other.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I always downvote them. "Any" questions are invariably just list questions.

Comment: @Valorum sure me too but like the “first of” questions they were deemed not list. Just another crappy loop hole in my opinion.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Yep, like I said "argued either way".

Comment: This seems like an ambiguous answer, so I'm not going to generate controversy by reposting the question. But clearly you all are sci-fi experts, so if you find another "realistic video chat" example, let me know?

Comment: @LevenTrek Didn't mean to be ambiguous. It's definitely on-topic if "only" is replaced by "first". (TLC's comment above refers to the *original* version of the question with "only".) Also, isn't Valorum's comment on your meta question another example?

Comment: Even one example makes my whole question moot - I didn't see it in Valorum's clip, but if it's there, then I'm done. And ambiguous was the wrong word - I should have said "ambivalent" (meaning that the question wasn't "rejected" but also didn't seem "encouraged")

Comment: @LevenTrek The version you just posted has none of the problems mentioned here, and I just upvoted it :-)

Comment: Thanks @Randal'Thor. I was trying to put some extra effort in so other people could get the answer I did, but I don't have the energy to debate critical comments and the (obviously wrong) duplicate label. Thanks for your support, but I think I'm just going to delete it.